# Change CCAnimation Frame Rate

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, frame-rate, ccaction

I am working on a sidescroller game in cocos2d.
I have a CCAction derived from a CCAnimation that runs on a CCSprite.
I run the CCAction with CCRepeatForever, but I’m not able to change the animation frame rate while the action is being performed.
How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Can you show your codes?

Comment: You have to stop whichever animation running on sprite and then initialize new CCAction with new animation frame rate and run that on sprite.

Comment: use CCSpeed which affects the speed of its inner actions

Comment: because the animation is quite short, I solved the issue simply by changing the frame rate whenever the loop ended and restarted the animation right after. Thank you anyways for the replies!